# accepting character in c++ with and without space

Tags: c++

What is the difference in the two codes where both accepts characters ?NOTE that there is a space in second way of accepting character ?

```
char c;
scanf("%c",&c);// first way
scanf(" %c",&c);// second way
```

Comment: your code does not compile

Answer (score 1):

You just have to look at the documentation for [`scanf`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=scanf&sektion=3)...

> White space (such as
>        blanks, tabs, or newlines) in the format string match any amount of white
>        space, including none, in the input.

Answer (score 1):

> C string that contains a sequence of characters that control how
>   characters extracted from the stream are treated:
>
> ### Whitespace character:
>
> the function will read and ignore any whitespace characters
>   encountered before the next non-whitespace character (whitespace
>   characters include spaces, newline and tab characters -- see isspace).
>   A single whitespace in the format string validates any quantity of
>   whitespace characters extracted from the stream (including none).
>
> ### Non-whitespace character, except format specifier (%):
>
> Any character that is not either a whitespace character (blank, newline or tab) or part of a format specifier (which begin with a % character) causes the
>   function to read the next character from the stream, compare it to
>   this non-whitespace character and if it matches, it is discarded and
>   the function continues with the next character of format. If the
>   character does not match, the function fails, returning and leaving
>   subsequent characters of the stream unread.
>
> ### Format specifiers:
>
> A sequence formed by an initial percentage sign (%) indicates a format
>   specifier, which is used to specify the type and format of the data to
>   be retrieved from the stream and stored into the locations pointed by
>   the additional arguments.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) of *cstdio*:

> **Whitespace character**: the function will read and ignore any whitespace characters encountered before the next non-whitespace
>   character (whitespace characters include spaces, newline and tab
>   characters -- see isspace). A single whitespace in the format string
>   validates any quantity of whitespace characters extracted from the
>   stream (including none).

So for the input `'asd'`, the value of `c` will be `'a'` for both versions. However, for an input of `' asd'` (note the whitespace!), the value of `c` will be `' '` for the first version and `'a'` for the second version.

Answer (score 0):

The first way will try to read one character.
The second way will try to read one or more characters: zero or more whitespace characters first, and a non-whitespace character after that, which will be placed into the 'c' variable.

But please note that *scanf* is a C legacy way of doing input, and is extremely error prone. You'll be better off with working with the [C++ Input/output library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io). Something like

```
std::cin >> c;
```

or

```
std::cin.get(c);
```

will do the work safer and better than *scanf*.

---

<sup>Edit: thanks to Tony D for clearing up things!</sup>

Comment: *"will try to read two or more characters: one or many whitespace"* - actually one or more, with zero or more whitespace.  `std::cin.get(&c);` - there's an overload taking a `char&`, but not one for `char*` (see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get)), so it should be `std::cin.get(c);`.